# Simple Voice recognition app on android not working as expected

Tags: java, android, xml, voice-recognition

A simple voice recognition app i coded is not working as I expected it. Basically, there are no visible errors on the log and it compiles fine, but when i click the button, the voice recognition feature pops up and starts recording, but after done recording, nothing appears on the app screen where the listview is supposed to show whatever was recorded (in text format)

Here is the java code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Voice extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    final static int check = 1111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        // set speech recognizer intent
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);  //set language
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak up son!");             // set prompt to user
        startActivityForResult(i, check);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // create an empty array list and link it to the recognizer intent
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            // link the listview from my layout to the arraylist I created just now with the results from voice recognition
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bVoice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click to Speak" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvVoiceReturn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Kalid could you try the language set as intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US"); and using debug or logs check if the app control goes to onActivityResult

Comment: Silly mistake. I hadnt connected to the internet. The app now works and Im surpised voice recognition requires connectivity. But thanks Aditi!